# Having trouble trying to solve bit level manipulation puzzle in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

So I have to use bitwise manipulation to solve this problem.

```
Should duplicate effect of C expression (x*63),
including overflow behavior.
Examples: multi63(1) = 63
   multi63(-1) = -63
Available ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
```

Maybe I'm not understanding what is being looked for but Im trying different variations and each time my result is either really close to what needs to be returned but isn't correct.

This is what I was currently playing with. I figured if I could mask x, which is the 1 perimeter, then I would know whether I'm multiplying by negative or positive.

```
int y = x>>31;

return ~(y^x)
```

This returns:

```
 Test times63(2147483647[0x7fffffff]) failed...
...Gives -2147483648[0x80000000]. Should be 2147483585[0x7fffffc1]
```

And If I try to return 2147483585[0x7fffffc1] it tells me I need to return -2147483648[0x80000000] so I'm confused as to what I need to return.

Comment: Well how are you multiplying by 63 here?

Comment: How about `y = (x << 6) + ~x + 1`, that is `y = x * 64 + -x`? Assuming a normal two's complement machine.

Comment: Ahhh I wasn't even thinking about the multiplying by 63, I was too focused on the positive/negative. Thanks, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: @user3769402: You don't need to bother with the signedness. Signed two's complement multiplication is equivalent to unsigned multiplication (modulo 2^N), much as in addition/subtraction.

Comment: Note that result of an overflow is only specified by the C programming language for unsigned integral types.

Comment: @Loic: True but staying within the bounds of fully portable C89 doesn't really leave much to work with. You'd pretty much be stuck doing a deeply inelegant chain of additions (`y = x, x += x, y += x, x += x, y += x..`).

Answer (score 1):

As a general(!) rule you can consider these formulas for an expression x*N, using shifts and addition/subtraction only:

A: (x << n) + (x << n-1) << + ... + << (x << m)

B: (x << n+1) - (x << m)

N can be viewed as a sequence of 0's and 1's [(0...0)(1...1)(0...0)(1...1)]. You have to consider runs of 1's from bit position `n` down to bit position `m`, where n == m is possible.

In your case N = 63, which is 011_1111 in binary. So we have n = 5 and m = 0.
As a simple example assume x = 2:

Using B: (2 << 6) - (2 << 0) == (2*64) - (2*1) == 128 - 2 == 126 (You can try out A for yourself, it works as fine.)

Just to demonstrate the process on another number, assume that N = 55 and x = 2. 55 in binary: 011_0111. This time we have two sequences of 1's. n1 = 5, m1 = 4 and n2 = 2 and m2 = 0.

Using B for n1/m1: (2 << 6) - (2 << 4) == (2*64) - (2*16) == 128 - 32 == 96

Using B for n2/m2: (2 << 3) - (2 << 0) == (2*8) - (2*1) == 16 - 2 == 14

Adding both results together yields 110, the desired value.